# Non-Repeating Database Design

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

If I need to keep member purchase history but also wanna keep my database as efficient as possible (3rd Normal Form) how would I do that keeping out repeating data? This is what I came up with:

**Bold** = Primary Key

Member(**memberID**, firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zip)

History(**historyID**, purchase, date, amount)

MemberHistory(**memberID**, **historyID**)

The thing with this is my history table will mean nothing on it's own and the joined table seems like it would have a bunch of repetition. Anybody 1) see problems with this design and 2) can inform me on a better way to keep a members history?

Comment: MemberHistory.memberID should probably be put directly in your History table since one row from History has one and one only memberID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `MemberHistory`, like so.

```
Member(memberID(PK), firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zip)

History(historyID(PK), memberID(PK/FK), purchase, date, amount)
```

there is no many-to-many relationship, so you won't need `MemberHistory`

Comment: If I have like 100 or 10,000 customers - wouldn't this become inefficient?

Comment: I'll answer your question with a question: how else would you store it? If you have 10,000 customers with 10 orders each, you have to save that info somehow; this looks to be the best way in a RDBMS. It's what I would do.